# How to get Instagram profile api?

Tags: flutter, api, instagram

I am not able to get api using https://www.instagram.com/deepjyoti_sam/?__a=1

some time this api worked but maximum time i not able to get rest api using this link

what is the right way to get instagram profile api ?

i test api using Postman latest version. also not working in my Flutter App. 100 out of 2 times worked for me.

error Code is showing on my Postman start with html ?? i want to see Rest API :---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js not-logged-in client-root">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>
        Login • Instagram
    </title>
```

Thank you